# How do I find the intersection points of two piecewise functions?

Tags: equation-solving, piecewise

I've got a piecewise function that is defined as follows:

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] :=  d + a /; a < b;
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] :=  d + b + (a - b)/10 /; a > b && b + (a - b)/10 < c;
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] :=  d + c /; b + (a - b)/10 >= c;
```

There is nothing fancy or complicated here.  This function basically has three linear regions; the only difference between these regions is the slope of the line.

I want to solve for the intersection point of two different cases of this function, for example:

```
Solve[f[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == f[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], x]
```

But I get this error:

```
Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients
or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present 
in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, 
providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>
```

I'm not sure what it means by "inexact coefficients" of "an exact version of the system".

I also tried `NSolve`, but this returns the original expression unchanged.

Comment: "inexact coefficients" refers to your use of numbers like `5.5`; try replacing those with exact versions like `11/2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your piecewise function a few different ways, here are two others,

```
f2[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Which[a < b, d + a, a > b && b + (a - b)/10 < c, d + b + (a - b)/10,
    b + (a - b)/10 >= c, d + c];

f3[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
  Piecewise[{{d + a, a < b}, {d + b + (a - b)/10, 
     a > b && b + (a - b)/10 < c}, {d + c, b + (a - b)/10 >= c}}];
```

They all give the same plot and show that there should be 2 intersection points,

```
Plot[{#[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32], #[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52]}, {x, 0, 
    20}] & /@ {f, f2, f3}
```

[image]

Using the `Which` or `Piecewise` commands, you can use `Solve` or `NSolve` easily enough,

```
Solve[#[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == #[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], 
   x] & /@ {f, f2, f3}
(* {Solve[f[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == f[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], 
  x], {{x -> 5.72222}, {x -> 14.}}, {{x -> 5.72222}, {x -> 14.}}} *)

NSolve[#[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == #[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], 
   x] & /@ {f, f2, f3}
(* {NSolve[f[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == f[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], 
  x], {{x -> 5.72222}, {x -> 14.}}, {{x -> 5.72222}, {x -> 14.}}} *)
```

But `FindRoot` will only work if you choose a starting point that

```
FindRoot[#[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == #[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], {x, 
    4}] & /@ {f, f2, f3}
FindRoot[#[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == #[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], {x, 
    7}] & /@ {f, f2, f3}
FindRoot[#[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == #[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52], {x, 
    5.6}] & /@ {f, f2, f3}
```

> During evaluation of In[16]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular
>   Jacobian at the point {x} = {4.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).
>
> During evaluation of In[16]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular
>   Jacobian at the point {x} = {4.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).
>
> During evaluation of In[16]:= FindRoot::jsing: Encountered a singular
>   Jacobian at the point {x} = {4.}. Try perturbing the initial point(s).
>
> During evaluation of In[16]:= General::stop: Further output of
>   FindRoot::jsing will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
(* {{x -> 4.}, {x -> 4.}, {x -> 4.}} *)
(* {{x -> 14.}, {x -> 14.}, {x -> 14.}} *)
(* {{x -> 5.72222}, {x -> 5.72222}, {x -> 5.72222}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
f[x_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Piecewise[{{d + x, x < b}, {d + b + (x - b)/10, 
    x > b && b + (x - b)/10 < c}, {d + c, b + (x - b)/10 >= c}}]

x /. Solve[
  Rationalize[f[x, 6.55, 6.55, 5.32] == f[x, 5.5, 6.5, 5.52]], x]
```

> `{103/18, 14}`